# C++ all Multiplication = zero

Tags: c++, math

When I put any number in for my comp var it puts out 0.  I tried it as an `int` originally and reading around looks like `double` is what I want.  I have tried the price var as just a `double` instead of `const double` as well.  I have to apply discounts according to the amount ordered for class and I'm just missing something any help would be appreciated:

```
const double price = 99.0; // price per unit
double comp;   // computer variable
double nodiscount = (price * comp);
double discount20 = (price * 0.8) * comp;   // 10-19 20%
double discount30 = (price * 0.7) * comp;   // 20-49 30%
double discount40 = (price * 0.6) * comp;   // 50-99 40%
double discount50 = (price * 0.5) * comp;   // 100 or more 50%

int main()
{
    cout << "How many units sold?" << endl;
    cin >> comp;

    if ( comp >= 0) {
        if ( comp <= 9 ) {
            cout << "Total cost of purchase is " << nodiscount  << endl;
        } else if ( comp >= 10 && comp <= 19) {
            cout << "The total cost with 20% discount is " << discount20 << endl;
        } else if ( comp >= 20 && comp <= 49) {
            cout << "The total cost with 30% discount is " << discount30 << endl;
        } else if ( comp >= 50 && comp <= 99) {
            cout << "The total cost with 40% discount is " << discount40 << endl;
        } else if ( comp >= 100 ) {
            cout << "The total cost with 50% discount is " << discount50 << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "you entered in invalid charechter pleas enter a number.";
    }
}
```

Comment: C++ for the most part executes things in the order you have them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compute `comp * whatever` *after* you figure out what `comp` is. As it is, you compute all the discounts with the default value of `comp = 0`. (Note that if `comp` were an uninitialized *local* variable, rather than global, it wouldn't default to 0. It would be indeterminate, and you would get all kinds of crazy nonsense.)